# how to filter a list based on null

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of items in C#.  Some of the items are null, some aren't.
How can I filter a list to only show the non-nulls?

```
 var countInstances = supervisor.SupervisedPlacements.Select(ps => ps.PlacementShift);
```

so how do I get only a list of non nulls from countInstances ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `Where` to remove the `null`s:

```
var filtered = supervisor.SupervisedPlacements.Where(x => x != null);

var countInstances = filtered.Count();
```

EDIT: I may have misunderstood.. here's another option (if this is what you meant):

```
var countInstances = supervisor
                         .SupervisedPlacements
                         .Select(ps => ps.PlacementShift)
                         .Where(ps => ps != null)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: In your first example, is that `.ToList()` really necessary?

Comment: No it is not. I'm so used to having to deal with IQueryable's its habit :/

Comment: If you are working with IQueryable it would be doubly important not to do `.ToList()`! If you did you would have to transmit the entire result set over the wire just to count it when the server could easily do it and transmit a single `int`.

Comment: ...with what I've been working on all week.. the results are filtered.. hence why they are IQueryable. This is just a habit from my weeks work.. not a recurring thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other comparison

```
(x => x.Foo != null)
```

Comment: whats foo though?  the results I get is countInstances[0] = null, countInstances[1] = object, countInstances[2] = null

Comment: Foo could be any property that needs to be tested to determine whether to include it in the results or not or the object itself as

(x => x != null)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all null from `countInstances`?

```
countInstances.RemoveAll(x => x == null);
```

but this will have direct effect on `countInstances`